# Best Apache Configuration

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, configuration, memory

Hi I have a VPS Linux server with RAM of 768Mb and My website is based on WordPress,which has over 50000 pageviews/day,In Recent times I got severe server overloading problem and came to know that Apache uses most memory,So if anybody could suggest me optimal Apache configuration

My current configuration is

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers       10
    MaxClients           30
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

WordPress as a software is bit on the heavy side. It's your PHP / MySQL / WordPress layer you should concentrate on tuning, I bet Apache itself is doing just fine -- for Apache less than one WP page view per second over the day should not be a problem. Here are some starting points for tuning:

- Have you installed any WP cache plugins, such as W3 Total Cache?
- Do you have any kind of PHP accelerator installed?
- How's your MySQL doing?

Also, what kind of problems your site has? Not loading at all? Loading very slowly? Pages gets loaded, but with errors?

Comment: yeah i have installed WP Total Cache plugin and I dont have any idea about PHP accelerator.see this memory usage stats http://img.freecircuits.org/images/screenoso.png ,At peaktimes site wont load at all and sometimes it get blank page.Most of the times it is slow only.